# Datatable - SelectedIndex in Combobox

Tags: c#, datatable, datagrid, selectedindex

Is it possible to add selectedIndex for combobox in dataTable in loop ?

```
 DataGridViewComboboxColumn dataGrid = new DataGridViewComboboxColumn();
 datagrid.Datasource = enumData; //this works 
 datagrid.Name = "cmb"

 Datatable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("cmb");
 for(int i = 0, i<200, i++)
 {
    var data = GetData(i);
    DataRow r =new DataRow();
    r["cmb] = data.value; //selectedIndex??

 }
```

Comment: What is your overall goal here? This seems like an XY problem. You can do this but even if you updated the UI (which it wont) the 200 indexes would flick past so quickly you wouldn't even see it happen. You'd be better off just setting the selected index to the last item after the loop is over. If you do something in the selectedindexchanged event you'd be better off calling that action on every row as it is added rather than using the eventing mechanism

Comment: Well, this works for row that is not a Combobox.

Comment: I beg to differ; it doesn't even compile, but that doesn't answer my question- what are you actually trying to do as an overall goal?

Comment: yeah because this is only part of code. I wanna bind selectedIndex for Combobox in row  I add. Later I add this datatable to datagridview. As I wrote earlier another type of data works for example textbox or checkbox but when I try  with combobox - not

Comment: It seems to me. He want to set information in the column with the combo box in the datagrid foreach element. datagrid....ComboBox.SelectedIndex=3;

Comment: You don't need to, if you bind the combobox properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a datagridview bound to a datatable, you don't mess with the individual combo boxes in the grid. You do something like this (I'll include the setup code):

```
DataTable sourceData = new DataTable();
sourceData.Columns.Add("Name");
sourceData.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(int));

sourceData.Rows.Add("John", 1);
sourceData.Rows.Add("Jane", 2);
sourceData.Rows.Add("Xxxx", 3);


DataTable comboData = new DataTable();
comboData.Columns.Add("Disp");
comboData.Columns.Add("Valu", typeof(int));


comboData.Rows.Add("Male", 1);
comboData.Rows.Add("Female", 2);
comboData.Rows.Add("Unspecified", 3);
```

And now for the nuts and bolts of it:

```
dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
dataGridView1.DataSource = sourceData;

//binding the dgv will create a couple of textbox columns, 
//now let's add a combo column to demo the binding concept


DataGridViewComboboxColumn dgvcbcGender = new DataGridViewComboboxColumn();
dgvcbcGender.Datasource = comboData; //refers to the male/female/unspecified table
dgvcbcGender.DisplayMember = "Disp"; //show john/jane/Xxxx in the combo
dgvcbcGender.ValueMember = "Valu"; //use the 1/2/3 ints as values to be stored in the sourceData table
dgvcbcGender.DataPropertyName = "Gender"; //critical! == "read the `Gender` int value of the row in `sourceData`, look it up in the `Valu` column of `comboData`
```

It is the last line that connects the list of items in the combo with the data in the main table. When binding is done like this we don't mess witht he selctedIndex of any combo at all; the combo will display the Male/Female/Unspecified related to the 1/2/3 it finds in the base row (`sourceData.Gender`) - it does this by looking up the value 1/2/3 in the `comboData.Valu` column. When you set a new Gender, it will take the corresponding SelectedValue out of the `comboData.Valu` and store it back in the row. You have another column bound to `sourceData.Gender` - see it change also when you change the setting in the combo box (maybe have to navigate to another row)

Now just make sure you add the column to the datagridview:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvcbcGender);
```

Comment: I don't understand. How do I associate combobox with a data row? I tried and it does not work :/

Comment: We don't do anything with comboboxes directly; we set up the datagridviewcomboxcolumn as per the code and then add it to the grid; it is the column that will create all the comboboxes (we don't touch them). Did you add the `dgvcbcGender` to the datagridview columns? I skipped that part out thinking it would be obvious but I should have probably put it in- edited

Comment: Yes, now it works thanks. I don't know why I didn't notice it and why it didn't work in my example. thanks so much!